# Implementing setTimeout native method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout, setinterval, browser-extension

I'm working on browser-extension in facebook, now my problem is that facebook override the setTimeout & setInterval native functions, and their implementation do not work on Internet Explorer.

Is there a way to implement those functions?

Comment: What did they do to them? Why don't they work in IE - I can't believe they could write an app without them?

Comment: i guess that they invoke them in some way, they do work for me on chrome and firefox and safari, only IE doesn't handle with there code.

Comment: If it's a browser extension, you could try to catch the methods before the Facebook script loads. eg `var myTimeout = setTimeout ;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create an iframe and then access it's `window` object, get the fresh `setTimeout` definition and overwrite the one in your global namespace :

```
var f = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(f);
window.setTimeout = f.contentWindow.setTimeout;
document.body.removeChild(f);
```

Although this works, it's probably not a good ideea for 2 scripts to start overwriting each other's variables. I suggest you let FB to *take control over the `setTimeout` function* and you use the fresh copy of it, but not to overwrite it again (you can store it in a local var, or in a global variable with another name).

Comment: IE9 Throw access denied when i'm trying to access contentWindow property, using contents() in jquery return the document and not the window object.